# how to get X and Y axis visible min and max values from Lightning Chart

Tags: lightningchart

I need to get values of visible X and Y axis from lightning chart,
I am using dashboard.createChartXy() with zoom band feature.

Answer (score 0):

The active interval of an Axis can be requested with [Axis.getInterval](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/axis.html#getinterval) method.

```
const xInterval = chart.getDefaultAxisX().getInterval()
console.log(xInterval.start, xInterval.end)
```